# Animate gif image consuming CPU in Flex 4.6 AIR Application

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flex4.5, gif

I am working with Flex 4.6 AIR application. What we've noticed that when animated GIFs are being displayed they are consuming between 5 and 8 percent of the CPU. I've confirmed it's definitely the GIF that is causing the CPU usage to increase so dramatically.

Has anyone else experienced this? Do you have work around? Does anyone have any idea why performance is so bad on this?

Comment: How are you displaying an animated GIF in a flex application?  Do MX:Image or s:Image support them?  Or something different?  You may consider switching from an animated GIF to a sprite sheet and making use of Blitting, although that may not be a trivial approach.

Comment: I am using the MX:HTML and creating it on rumtime.

protected function loadImage(source:String):void
   {    
    var animateGif:HTML = new HTML();
    animateGif.location = source;    
    animateGif.height = 142;
    animateGif.width = 180;      
    animateGif.horizontalScrollPolicy = "off";
    animateGif.verticalScrollPolicy = "off";
    animateGif.buttonMode = true;
    animateGif.useHandCursor = true;
    this.addElement(animateGif);    
   }

Where source is the path of the Animate GIF Image.

Comment: Thanks Reboog711, for your reply. What is Blitting ? If you have any code for that please give it to me.

Comment: I'm not surprised that using mx:HTML to render an animated GIF is performance intensive.  You're basically initializing a full webkit instance just to display the image.  Blitting is the process of rendering something off-screen, usually a sprite sheet, and writing portions of it onto the screen in order to make the 'graphic' animate. It is how most game animation is done. You should Google blitting in Flash or something similar for more information. As I said, it won't be a trivial change.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider converting GIF files to SWF and then embed them into your application.